# How can I get my search query to show up in URL?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

Using MVC 4

I have a partial view where I am creating a a search box.
When the submit button is clicked it then passes the value of my search to the control to filter my groups.

Everything filters just fine.  However the url I am hoping to get after performing the action is not coming up.  I just get localhost/

What I would like to show up would be localhost/mySearchValue

The routing in my project is set up so that if I were to type a value after local host it would then filter the groups just as my search button does.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get my search value to show up in the URL?

Here is my partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("List","Group"))
{ 
   @Html.TextBox(name: "search")
   <input type="submit"  value="search" />
}
```

My Controller

```
public ViewResult List(string search, int page = 1)
    {
        if (search == "")
        {
            search = null;
        }
        GroupsListViewModel model = new GroupsListViewModel
        {
            Groups = repository.Groups
            .Where(g => search == null || g.Tag == search || g.Tag2 == search)
            .OrderBy(g => g.GroupId)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = repository.Groups.Count()
            },
            CurrentSearch = search
        };
```

*Update*

```
@Html.BeginForm("List","Group",FormMethod.Get)
```

Helps me get a url as follows localhost/?search=test however search is not being set when the controller is called and so no filtering happens.  My url schema for searching is as follows localhost/test

Here is my routing information

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(null, 
            "",
            new { 
                controller = "Group", action = "List",
                search = (string)null, page = 1
            }
    );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
            "Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Group", action = "List", search = (string)null },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{search}",
            new { Controller = "Group", action = "List", page = 1 }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{search}/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Group", action = "List" },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
    }
```

Comment: It is fairly difficult to get it to show as localhost/mySearchValue. If the form uses POST, all you get is localhost, if the form uses GET, you will see localhost/group/list?mySearchValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Description

As long as i understand the question

Default form method is `POST` so you need set the form method to `GET` in order to see the search string in the url.

Please let me know (as a comment) if i dont understand what your want in order to help you more)

### Sample

```
@Html.BeginForm("List","Group",FormMethod.Get)
```

### More Information

- [MSDN - FormExtensions.BeginForm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this does work to where I am seeing my search query in the URL as follows http://localhost/?search=test.  However now when the list method of my controller is called my search parameter is null so no filtering happens.  With my current url routing http://localhost/test will filter out the results for me.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looking at your link I'm guessing BeginForm(HtmlHelper, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, FormMethod) might do the trick.. Are you familiar with the RouteValueDictionary parameter?

Comment: Well I believe its not filtering because I need the url to look like localhost/searchFilter instead of localhost/?search=searchFilter do you know how to accomplish this using the RouteValueDictionary?